# delete lines from file in python

Tags: python, file-io, file-processing

I have a file formated like this：

```
#1  0.13297254902 0.324803921569 0.434835294118 ...#many floats in one line
#2  0
#3  0.377305882353 0.595870588235 0.353215686275 ...
#4  1 #0/1 for the second line 
#5  ....
```

I want to process the file so that all blocks with second line is 0 can be deleted and left the file as

```
#1  0.377305882353 0.595870588235 0.353215686275 ...
#2  1
#3  0.403529411765 0.341654901961 0.379278431373 ... 
#4  1 #now they are all 1s
#5  .....
```

I tried the snippet below, but it can only see the 0/1 then remove the line, but I want to delete the line with floats above 0/1, not the line with floats below 0/1.

```
f = open(filePath, "r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
f = open(filePath, "w")

for line in lines:
    if "1\n" in line:
        f.write(line)
```

Is there any other way I can choose which line to include and which not?
Or maybe there's a way to process the file backwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `next()` function to get the next element in the file iterable. The `shutil` module allows us to move the new file, overwriting the original (thanks @JoranBeasley).

```
import shutil

with open(filePath, 'r') as f, open('new_' + filePath, 'w') as output:
    for line in f:
        n = next(f)
        if n != '0\n':
            output.write(line+n)

shutil.move("new_" + filePath, filePath)
```

Input:

```
0.13297254902 0.324803921569 0.434835294118 ...#many floats in one line
0
0.377305882353 0.595870588235 0.353215686275 ...
1 #0/1 for the second line
```

Output:

```
0.377305882353 0.595870588235 0.353215686275 ...
1 #0/1 for the second line
```

Comment: Yeah, it works! But is it possible to store them into the same file?

Comment: `shutil.move("new_filepath.txt", filepath)`?

Comment: Mandary: You can do relatively easy in-place file modification using the [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#module-fileinput) module.

Comment: @martineau ... but doesnt that require using its closure context(ie `with fileinput.open(asdasd)`?) in which case you cannot call next on its iterator? .. so that wouldnt work I dont think(at least not without some sledgehammering) ...

Comment: Thanks, @JoranBeasley - it'll now overwrite the original as desired.

Comment: @Joran: If you can do `for line in f` where `f` is a `fileinput.FileInput` instance, you should be able to do `next(f)`.

Comment: oh your right ... I had just never used it like that :P